How to properly implement a ListView inside a RecyclerView?
In each RecyclerView element, only the first ListView element is displayed.
I'm making an application for passing tests. There may be a different number of answers to each question. There will be an activity in the application that displays a list of all the questions with all the answers, where the correct answer will be marked in color.
Adapter Class:
class QuestionsAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionsAdapter.QuestionHolder>() {
    private val questionsList = ArrayList<Question>()

    class QuestionHolder(item: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) {

        private val questionBinding = QuestionItemBinding.bind(item)

        fun bind(question: Question, position: Int) = with(questionBinding) {

            val questionText = "${position + 1}. ${question.text}"
            recyclerQuestion.text = questionText
            recyclerAnswerList.adapter = AnswersAdapter(this.root.context, R.layout.answer_item_for_questions_list, question.answers)

        }

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): QuestionHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.question_item, parent, false)
        return QuestionHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return questionsList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: QuestionHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(questionsList[position], position)
    }

    fun addQuestion(question: Question) {
        questionsList.add(question)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun addAllQuestions(questions: MutableList<Question>) {
        questionsList.addAll(questions)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}

XML File:
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerQuestion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerAnswerList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:dividerHeight="3dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


There is no good reason to use ListView in a RecyclerView child.  Just use another RecyclerView.
